# Queries in RabbitMQ Federation Multi Region setup for DR

Tags: disaster-recovery-plans, rabbitmq

Below is my current setup:

- RabbitMq cluster of 3 nodes in AWS us-east-1 region across 3 AZs with a load balancer.
- And I have set up one additional  RabbitMq instance in AWS us-west-2 region for DR purposes.

I have established the federation link to the upstream cluster(us-east-1 region) to replicate the messages and have a few queries regarding the same.

**Q1**) I have used federated exchanges and our setup has around 100 queues that use the same exchange with different routing keys
example -

Exchange 1
-->Queue 1 --routing key 1
-->Queue 2 --routing key 2
--> ...
--> ...
--> Queue n - routing key n

Is there any way to replicate messages selectively based on the combination of both exchange and routing keys as I don't want to replicate all the messages in the DR region?

**Q2**) In the federation upstream I had specified the URI of the load balancer in the `uri` parameters. So does that mean it will replicate messages from all the 3 nodes in the cluster to the downstream node?
If yes, will the message sequencing be guaranteed?